# javascript match and add string in dynamic Url

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have a dynamic URL, which i want to append some string at last

```
 'http://staging.mydomain.name.com/test/7bb12c5f7b2f4f008261bea2d3f5abd2/200x200.png'
```

want to append "preview" before size (200x200.png which is also dynamic), something like below

```
'http://staging.mydomain.name.com/test/7bb12c5f7b2f4f008261bea2d3f5abd2/preview/200x200.png'
```

I have seen  [Javascript match to remove part of file name from URL - replace the last occurence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188561/javascript-match-to-remove-part-of-file-name-from-url-replace-the-last-occuren) but its not what i want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple regular expression like:

```
'http://.../200x200.png'.replace(/[^\/]+$/, 'preview/$&')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like str.replace(/(/\d+x\d+.)/,'/preview$1')